# How to show unsynchronicity of arraylist java?

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, thread-safety

We know that **ArrayList** are not thread safe and **VectorList** are. I wanted to make a program to show that operation are being performed synchronously in VectorList and not in ArrayList. The only problem, I am facing is how? What kind of operation? 
For example :- If we add a value to any of the list, the program simply add values.
I tried to make one but realized the synchronicity my program is dependent on variable j, not on ArrayList or VectorList.

```
public class ArrayDemo implements Runnable {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int j = 0;
    public void run() {
        while ( j < 10) {
            int i = random.nextInt(10);
            al.add(i);
            System.out.println(i + " "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            j++;
            //System.out.println(al.remove(0));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDemo ad = new ArrayDemo();
        Thread t = new Thread(ad);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ad);
        t.start();t1.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: hey i tried searching for it, but it keeps taking me to different more useful topics not such basic examples.

Comment: If you want to test thread (un)safety you will have to access/modify the same collection with multiple threads. Now you are creating 2 Vectors and accessing each one with a single thread.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake let me correct and see.

Comment: Also, as you pointed out, ArrayList is the one that is not thread-safe so maybe test that one first and once you prove it's unsafe use the same test with the Vector.

Comment: Both program for ArrayList and VectorList are running smoothly. Now the part how to show that one is (un)safe.

Comment: Yes, you will have to do a lot of fast operations. Don't limit yourself to 10 loops, go with while(true). Remove random and system.out calls as these are usually slower calls and would reduce the chance of an inconsistent state happening. Just focus on calling `Add(obj)` (or `Add(index, obj)`) from both threads and possibly recreating the ArrayList from one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small test program:

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test(new Vector<>());
        test(new ArrayList<>());
        test(Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
        test(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>());
    }
    private static void test(final List<Integer> list) throws Exception {
        System.gc();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
            threads[i] = new Test(list);
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(list.size() + " in " + (end - start) + "ms using " + list.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    private final List<Integer> list;
    Test(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                this.list.add(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
100000 in 16ms using Vector
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 466
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:459)
    at Test.run(Test.java:36)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 465
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:459)
    at Test.run(Test.java:36)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:459)
    at Test.run(Test.java:36)
32507 in 15ms using ArrayList
100000 in 16ms using SynchronizedRandomAccessList
100000 in 3073ms using CopyOnWriteArrayList
```

As you can see, with [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) it completes normally and returns `100000`, which is the expected size after adding 10000 values in 10 parallel threads.

With [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) you see two different failures:

- Three of the threads die with [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in the call to `add()`.
- Even if the three failing threads died immediately, before adding anything, the other 7 threads should still have added 10000 values each, for a total of `70000` values, but the list only contains `32507` values, so many of the added values got lost.

The third test, using [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-), works like `Vector`.

The fourth test, using the concurrent [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), also generates the right result, but much slower, due to excessive copying. It will however be faster than synchronized access if the list is smaller and changes rarely, but is read often.
It is especially good if you need to iterate the list, because even `Vector` and `synchronizedList()` will fail with [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) if the list is modified while iterating, while `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will iterate a snapshot of the list.

---

Out of curiosity, I checked some [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementations too:

```
test(new ArrayDeque<>());
test(new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>());
test(new LinkedBlockingDeque<>());
```

*Sample Output*

```
34295 in 0ms using ArrayDeque
100000 in 15ms using ConcurrentLinkedDeque
100000 in 16ms using LinkedBlockingDeque
```

As you can see, the unsynchronized [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) shows the "lost value" symptom, though it doesn't fail with an exception.

The two concurrent implementations, [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), work good and fast.

Comment: Great answer, easy to understand. I haven't even used half of the collection you implemented. One more thing, could you explain the "lost value" symptom you mentioned for ArrayDeque.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta That's the second bullet you also see for `ArrayList`. I was simply trying to refer back to that.

Answer (score 1):

Even with your simple program you could show that the `ArrayList` is not thread safe by making more loop iterations (10 might not be enough) and reduce other code that slows down operations on `ArrayList`, especially IO code such as `System.out`.

I modified your original code by removing `Random` and `System.out` calls. I added just a single `System.out.println` at the end of the loop to show possible successful termination.

However this code does not run in full. Instead it throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: ...
```

What is important to learn from this is that even similar code might not run into thread-safety issues if the timings are not just right. This shows why thread related bugs are hard to find and can lurk in code for very long before they actually crash the program.

Here is the modified code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayDemo implements Runnable {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int j = 0;
    public void run() {
        while (j < 10000) {
            al.add(new Integer(1));
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("Array size: " + al.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDemo ad = new ArrayDemo();
        Thread t = new Thread(ad);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ad);
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }

}
```